# Adding variable to constraint in pyomo

Tags: python, pyomo, column-generation

I am trying to implement a delayed column generation approach in pyomo.
However, I cannot find a way to add a variable to a constraint. I can add variables to the objective function, simply by adding to the objective expression, but that does not seem to work with constraints. So my question is "can you add a variable to an existing constraint in pyomo"? To illustrate what I want to do, here is small example (which does not work):

```
import pyomo.environ as pyomo
# Create model and variable
model = pyomo.ConcreteModel()
model.x = pyomo.Var(within=pyomo.NonNegativeReals)
# Create simple initial model
model.obj = pyomo.Objective(expr=model.x, sense=pyomo.minimize)
model.cst = pyomo.Constraint(expr=model.x >= 2)
# Solve the model
solver = pyomo.SolverFactory('gurobi')
solver.solve(model, tee=True)
# Create new variable
model.y = pyomo.Var(within=pyomo.NonNegativeReals)
# Add a new variable to the objective and to the constraint
model.obj.expr += model.y
model.cst.body += model.y # This does not work!
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using an `Expression` object to hold the part of the constraint you want to modify:

```
import pyomo.environ as pyomo

# Create model and variable
model = pyomo.ConcreteModel()
model.x = pyomo.Var(within=pyomo.NonNegativeReals)

# Create simple initial model
model.obj = pyomo.Objective(expr=model.x, sense=pyomo.minimize)
model.lhs_expr = pyomo.Expression(expr=model.x)
model.cst = pyomo.Constraint(expr=model.lhs_expr >= 2)

# Solve the model
solver = pyomo.SolverFactory('gurobi')
solver.solve(model, tee=True)

# Create new variable
model.y = pyomo.Var(within=pyomo.NonNegativeReals)

# Add a new variable to the objective and to the constraint
model.obj.expr += model.y
model.lhs_expr += model.y
```

Comment: Thanks! This is certainly a step forward (after banging my head against this for too long)! Next problem seems to be that Pyomo isn't providing an "ExpressionList" as is the case for VarList and ConstraintList. And simply storing the expressions in a python list, seems to make pyomo angry again. Do you known a way around this? Say I have 100 constraints, where I want to  be able to access the `lhs_expr` for each of them.

Comment: One way is to index the `Expression` by the Pyomo set `Any`. This gives you the behavior of something like an "ExpressionList" but you have more control of the indexing sets. For example: 
`model.lhs_expr = pyomo.Expression(pyomo.Any)`,
`model.lhs_expr[1] = model.x`,
`model.lhs_expr[2] = model.x**2`,
`model.lhs_expr.pprint() # Will print only indices that have been defined`

Comment: Just make sure you're using the latest Pyomo version (6.4.2) when using the `+=` operator with `Expression` components. There was a bug with this operation prior to that release (see: https://github.com/Pyomo/pyomo/pull/2493)